# How to transition laminate flooring to this prefab threshold?

Tags: laminate-floor, transition

I know I should leave a gap around all edges of free-floating laminate flooring, but I'm not sure how to do that in front of this door.  **What should I use to cover the gap?**

This is an outswing exterior door.  It's one of those prefabs where the door is already hung in the frame and they just screw the whole thing into the opening.  The interior edge of the threshold has a groove in it that looks like I could press in a weather strip or something.  Is there a type of transition molding made for this?

[image]

Comment: We install the laminate tight to thresholds and clear caulk; but this does not leave the require 1/4-1/2" gap spec'd in the manuals.  If we did that, our clients would not be happy because there would be little gaps here and there.

Comment: I have this problem, too.  I think that the carpet strip would be quite unattractive.  It seems difficult to match the T-shaped covers I've seen to the flooring.  I wish I saw a good answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd use an edge molding tight against the vertical face of the threshold.

[image]

This might result in a small v-notch which collects dirt, but it would look polished. You could always fill with a small bead of clear silicone.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, though I used a product with a different profile. I undercut the ends so the laminate has the required gap, but no gap is visible.

Answer (score 2):

A silver carpet strip should do nicely there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They're called end caps and you have to have know how, but they're not difficult to figure out. 12 years of flooring under my belt.

Answer (score -1):

There are T mouldings that replace the threshold and cover the laminate on 1 side and the other side is in tight contact. Some have a track that is screwed down that the new threshold snaps into others are screwed down like traditional thresholds. Pinching the laminate with old school types can be troublesime if a floating type floor. The damage can be as simple as buckling , or rubbing through the top layer as the floor moves in a high tragic area like this. ( I have seen floors do ok with old school but have also seen the surface damage and buckling).

Comment: I don't think I can remove the old threshold.  As I said, it's one of those prefab pre-hung doors.  There are no fasteners visible anywhere on the threshold.  I think it was attached to the sides from the bottom.

Comment: A hack saw or saws all with a fine tooth blade could cut it out and install a single threshold.